# Can only find disk letters inside IDLE

Tags: python, psutil

I've written a python script that finds disk letters and it uses psutil. When I run this script from command prompt it says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'` but it runs perfectly when I run it from IDLE.

I tried to upgrade psutil but it didn't work. Then I tried to reinstall it and it didn't work again. So how can I fix this problem?

> OS: Windows 8.1
>
> Python Version: 3.7.3
>
> Psutil Version: 5.6.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it. I can simply run it like this:

`python diskletter.py`